# android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL on older Android versions

Tags: android

I have an application that works fine on Android >21. But when I run it on Android 18, I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user 
asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; 
this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser
...
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.example.MainActivity" on path:
/data/app/com.example-1.apk
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
…
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.example.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example-1.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.
…
E/Launcher: Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: 
Accessibility_enabled
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Can this be solved by setting additional permissions? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a signature level permision, which would not work unless your app has the same signature with the android device you are trying to run your app on, this feature is mostly unavailable to most developers and varies with API.

For more info read the Android Developers page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: i keep reading about the CAUSE of the problem, but no solution.  What is the solution?

Comment: nay sir @Shivam Pokhriyal, people seem to say if you add `<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/> ` to your AndroidManifest.xml, it will solve the problem.  but for reasons outlined in this response, I feel like it won't work.  This bug is hard to repro for me (and I haven't been able to repro) so I've decided to just continue.  lmk if you find a solution.  Or a way to repro the bug consistently.

Comment: @sudocoder Actually I haven't been able to reproduce it myself.